# create files with node and replace variables with prompt input

Tags: javascript, node.js, prompt

I wrote a little script in `JavaScript` which will create some `.php` files.

The content of these files is stored in `text.txt` format which is the blueprint of my generated files.

When my script runs, I want to copy the content of these files and generate the `.php` files. This works but I want to change some variables in this file.

For example the `Name` in the document.

```
Hello, variable.name
```

How can I create a `text.txt` file with variables, which will replace the variables with my `prompt()` input?

```
$ prompt: name: Helena
```

So after the prompt, I want my files to look like this:

```
"Hello, Helena"
```

Comment: You can use some predefined string like `#something#` and replace it with the value that you want, and create the file you want

Comment: show the file has a special doc type? i use .txt.. i used #variable.name# but i only get the string i typed and not the value which is stored in my data object. i load the file via fs.writeFileSync()

Comment: File type does not matter, just read the contents as a string, and manipulate it

Comment: ok but can you give a little advise? or example?

Answer (score 0):

I googled some links for you

Read [this](https://code-maven.com/reading-a-file-with-nodejs) to read content of a file in node

```
var fs = require('fs');
var contents = fs.readFileSync('DATA', 'utf8');
console.log(contents);
```

Read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to replace text

```
var p = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. If the dog reacted, was it really lazy?';

var regex = /dog/gi;

console.log(p.replace(regex, 'ferret'));
// expected output: "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy ferret. If the ferret reacted, was it really lazy?"
```